# Exporting/Viewing the whole Tensor (764-d)

Tags: python, tensorflow, sentiment-analysis

I need to export the formed tensor for which I used this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel

def get_embeddings(model_name,tokenizer,name,inp):
    tokenizer = tokenizer.from_pretrained(name)
    model = model_name.from_pretrained(name)
    input_ids = tf.constant(tokenizer.encode(inp))[None, :]  # Batch size 1
    outputs = model(input_ids)
    last_hidden_states = outputs[0]
    cls_token=last_hidden_states[0]
    return cls_token
cls_token=get_embeddings(TFBertModel,BertTokenizer,'bert-base-uncased',z[0])
cls_token
```

I received the following output:

```
Some layers from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased were not used when initializing TFBertModel: ['nsp___cls', 'mlm___cls']
- This IS expected if you are initializing TFBertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing TFBertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
All the layers of TFBertModel were initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased.
If your task is similar to the task the model of the checkpoint was trained on, you can already use TFBertModel for predictions without further training.
<tf.Tensor: shape=(21, 768), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.24550161, -0.34956726,  0.01089635, ..., -0.38017362,
        -0.03965453,  0.41104677],
       [ 0.4436314 , -0.3720695 ,  0.27837285, ...,  0.7340785 ,
        -0.02534109, -0.24059379],
       [ 0.00089747, -0.18920937,  0.83858776, ...,  0.58318835,
        -0.03517005, -0.29172006],
       ...,
       [-0.06368805,  0.00210648,  0.52235216, ...,  0.32049924,
        -0.06555019,  0.20605275],
       [-0.10185663, -0.53307414, -0.37091127, ..., -0.17225765,
        -0.45891476,  0.30040386],
       [ 0.59691334,  0.12757768, -0.27682877, ..., -0.07072508,
        -0.6099813 , -0.00861905]], dtype=float32)>
```

I want to export/view the full tensor either in array or CSV format, preferably the latter.

Comment: Use tensor.numpy() to convert the tensor to a numpy array and then export it in a file?!

Comment: @Sohrab I'm sorry I'm a noob at this. Could you please walk me through the steps?